# Using filter in list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a Blog App and I am trying to access `first posts of all the users` in last `2 days`, So i am using solution for accessing first posts.

when i use `filter of last 2 days` then the first post method is not working. So i thought `"I should use filter in another query"`

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def first_posts(request):
    time = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=2)

    posts = [user.blogpost_set.first() for user in User.objects.prefetch_related(
                                                          'blogpost_set')].filter(blogpost__date__gte=time)

    context = {'posts':posts}
```

But it showed

> 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

- I also tried using :-

```
ALL_POSTS = []


for post in posts:
    ALL_POSTS.append(post).filter(post__date=time)
```

But it showed

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter

I will really appreciate your Help.

Thank You

Comment: try this:- 

posts = [user.blogpost_set.filter(date__gte=time).first() for user in User.objects.all()]

Comment: If you want ignore None Post in list.

posts = [user.blogpost_set.filter(date__gte=time).first() for user in User.objects.all() if user.blogpost_set.filter(date__gte=time).first()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by **user** query as a subquery.

```
two_days_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=2)

# get first blog_post_id user-wise in last two days
post_ids_subquery = BlogPost.objects.filter(
                            date__gt=two_days_ago
                        ).values(
                            'user'
                        ).annotate(
                            min_id=Min('id')
                        ).values('min_id')
# get objects for that blog_post_ids for accessing all fields of models
queryset = BlogPost.objects.filter(id__in=post_ids_subquery)
```

Edit:
post_ids_subquery query is similar to:

```
print(post_ids_subquery.query) 

SELECT MIN(`blog_post`.`id`) AS `min_id` FROM `blog_post` WHERE `blog_post`.`created_at` > {two_days_ago} GROUP BY `blog_post`.`user_id`
```

when you apply **group_by** query then its gets **user_wise data** then applying Min('id') function , it gets **minumum id of each user_wise data**. Since id is auto-incremental id , so min_id gives first blog_post_id for each user.

Comment: Can you explain me , How is `id's subquery` is working ?

Comment: @Lars I added subquery description.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you tried to filter a list.

> ````py
>     time = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=2)
>
>     posts = [user.blogpost_set.first() for user in User.objects.prefetch_related('blogpost_set')].filter(blogpost__date__gte=time)
>
>     context = {'posts':posts} ```
> ````

It should be like this,

```py
posts = [user.blogpost_set.first() for user in User.objects.prefetch_related('blogpost_set').filter(blogpost__date__gte=time).order_by("blogpost__date")]
```

In this query we fetched Users who has blogposts and filter them with given time and order them with blogpost date. Thus this gives us first post of Users who has posts. (User without post are not included)

Then, in second try list append method returns None thus you are getting this error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter

Comment: Thanks for your Time, But it is including every posts but **Not** only first Post